# Brand-new Debian STS install is crashing on startup

Tags: linux, eclipse, spring, debian

Any idea on how to work around this issue?

```
!SESSION 2014-11-27 09:06:02.049 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.6.2.201410091308-RELEASE-e44
java.version=1.8.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=pt_BR
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-11-27 09:06:15.048
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:918)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the cause of the problem. It is reported on Bug 430736 at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430736. Some internal dependencies were loading both GTK2 and GTK3, and it was causing either Eclipse/STS to crash on startup. Solution is to set GTK3 to zero with

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

I did it on the root console and started either Eclipse and STS normally through console.